# What exactly would be the direction of motion of a ball spun counterclockwise in air?

Tags: aerodynamics

I know that this relates to the Magnus effect in fluid dynamics but I haven't been able to understand how the resultant force due to air drag would be useful in sports like cricket and tennis. In what direction would a ball move - upward, downward, leftward or rightward if it is spun in a particular direction?

Answer (score 0):

You are spinning the wire counter-clockwise. If the axis is vertical then the ball would be spinning faster near the axis which means slower at the mid-surface. The pressure is more on the side having low velocity so the central region of the ball will have more pressure flowing from the central region to the low-pressure region so the ball is going to raise upwards.

Comment: I think you have mixed up your orientations: if the ball is spinning about a vertical axis the pressure difference is in the horizontal plane.